# ios AVPlayerViewController can not play local mp4

Tags: ios, video, avplayerviewcontroller

I tried to use `AVPlayerViewController` play mp4 video. I use "http url", it can play, but when I use `fileUrl`, it does not work...

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mp4ForDownloadTest" ofType:@"mp4"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

    AVPlayerViewController *playerVC = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

    AVAsset *movieAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:movieAsset];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    playerVC.player = player;

    [self presentViewController:playerVC animated:YES completion:^{
        [player play];
    }];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("drum", ofType:"mp4") else {
            break
        }

        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        self.loadPlayer(url)
```

then:

```
private func loadPlayer(url: NSURL) {
    // present video window
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
    let player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerViewController.player = player

    self.view.addSubview(self.playerViewController.view)
    self.videoControlView.alpha = 1.0
    self.setupPlayerObserver()
    self.playPlayer()
    self.setSlider()
}
```